# $\lambda = \max_{\mathbf{x}}\frac{\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{x}}$ for non-negative matrices $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, variational-analysis

Let $A$ be a non-negative irreducible matrix. By the Perron-Frobenius theorem, the eigenvalue of max. absolute value $\lambda$ is positive and has an eigenvector of all positive entries.

Is it true that

$$\max_{\mathbf{x}}\frac{\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{x}}$$

where, perhaps, the max. is taken only over non-negative vectors $\mathbf x $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.  As a simple example, consider the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{10 & 99\\1 & 10}
$$
Its maximal eigenvalue is $10 + 3 \sqrt{11} \approx 19.95$.  However,
$$
\max_x \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx} = \frac{(1,1)^T A(1,1)}{2} = 60
$$

Comment: This answers my question. But how do you know that the $max$ occurs at $(1,1)$?

Comment: Rayleigh's theorem.  Note that
$$
x^TAx = x^T\pmatrix{10&50\\50&10}x
$$

Comment: @becko: Or use Lagrange multipliers on the problem $\max\{ x^T A x | \|x \| =1 \}$ to see that the $\max$ must occur at an eigenvector. Then Perron Frobenius shows that this must be the (unique) $\max$ real eigenvalue and that the result is the same as the stricter problem with $x>0$.